# How to fix this error: You are trying to use contextless navigation without a GetMaterialApp or Get.key

Tags: android, ios, flutter, button, navigation

You are trying to use contextless navigation without
a GetMaterialApp or Get.key.
If you are testing your app, you can use:
[Get.testMode = true], or if you are running your app on
a physical device or emulator, you must exchange your [MaterialApp]
for a [GetMaterialApp].

This is the error that i get when i press on the button. How can i fix this error and make the button work.

The code:

````
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:hetmaantje/constants.dart';
import 'package:hetmaantje/quiz_screen.dart';

class welcome_screen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/bg.svg", fit: BoxFit.fill),
          SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPadding),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Spacer(flex: 2), //2/6
                  Text(
                    "Let's Play Quiz,",
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4?.copyWith(
                        color: Colors.pink.shade100, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Text("Enter your informations below"),
                  Spacer(), // 1/6
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Color(0xFF1C2341),
                      hintText: "Full Name",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Spacer(), // 1/6
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () => Get.to(quiz_screen()),
                    child: Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultPadding * 0.75), // 15
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: kPrimaryGradient,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        "Lets Start Quiz",
                        style: Theme.of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .button
                            ?.copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Spacer(flex: 2), // it will take 2/6 spaces
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```
````

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `main.dart` file, replace **`MaterialApp`** with **`GetMaterialApp`**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      //
    );
}
```

Check Step 1 of Getx Package documentation
[Documentation Link](https://pub.dev/packages/get#counter-app-with-getx)